# Don't know where to start in learning about sockets and connecting mobile devices?

Tags: android, websocket, imessage

So I want to be able to connect my android device to my iPhone, and use that connection as a bridge to get the iMessage service "on" my android. Now these people [here](http://www.remotemessages.com/) have already done just that, unfortunately it doesn't look like they're going to be making it into a messenger application like I want to.

So that is just my end goal, and because I have just started to become proficient with java, that goal is a long ways a way, which is why I was hoping some one could give an explanation as to how they manage to make their remote messages web application work, so I can 'get the ball rolling'.

So if someone could dumb it down and explain what is going on from the time I run the remote messages web application to the time I send a text message I would be very appreciative. I hope the this isn't too vague of a question. I am just trying to get an idea of what I need to start learning.

Thank You

Comment: Receive new message on iPhone.  App on iPhone sees new message arrive.  Send new message to your server with ajax call.  Server sends message to Android phone via Google push service.  App on Android phone receives message.  It also might be possible that there's an Apple API (you'd have to research this) your server could use to receive the new message directly from Apple's infrastructure

Comment: Would it be possible to use the iPhone as its own server

Comment: Also is this what your talking about?http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php--net-17693

Comment: Sure, the iPhone can be server, but you'd have to figure out if it's possible to send data directly from the iPhone to your target Android device.  That is usually the problem.